# Which IP do I have to sub/pub in a mosquitto broker on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have deployed a mosquitto image in a pod in kubernetes with this dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.7
```

I downloaded the image an added it to my cluster, using this yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-demo
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      bb: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        bb: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bb-site
        image: mosquittotest:1.0
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    bb: web
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30001
```

It is running correctly.

My question is: How can I know which IP is the one I should use t sub/pub, and which port?
Do I just have to use the IP of the entrypoint service with the 8080 port?

I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 2):

Do you get an IP-address on the Service?

### Using ClusterIP

To have an cluster interal IP, you should set `type=ClusterIP` on your service:

```
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
```

Your clients route it requests to a DNS name for the service, depending on how your namespaces are setup. See [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

### Using NodePort

If you want to continue using type=NodePort, you can send request to the IP for any Node, but with the specific Node Port number.